# SNMP not working in amazon server

Tags: snmp, snmpd

I'm trying to monitor amazon server from my local server,I installed and configured snmpd but I can't arrive from my local server to amazon server using snmpwalk.

I check it with the command:

> snmpwalk -Os -c public -v 2c XX.XX.XX.XX

from amazon server the snmp is working correctly but from local server is not working.

The SNMP configuration in amazon server is:

> agentAddress  udp:0.0.0.0:161
>
> view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
>
> view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1
>
> rocommunity public  0.0.0.0

The configuration in /etc/default/snmp is:

> SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid'

and the security group in amazon server I opened UDP to anywhere:

> Custom UDP Rule - UDP - 161 - 0.0.0.0/0

-- Netstat result:

> root@#  netstat -an | grep 161
>
> udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:161             0.0.0.0:*

-- In my firewall i added this rule:

> # cat rules | grep 161
>
> ACCEPT loc:ip_local_server net:ip_amazon_server  udp 161

I don't know what I have to check more.

any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: SNMP traffic could be blocked by firewall. Try installing wireshark to sniff network packets.

Answer (score 0):

Lunching tcpdump I see this result in amazon server when I lunch snmpwalk in my local server:

> 17:38:23.591513 IP 1-1-1-1.ea.com.35403 > .snmp:  GetNextRequest(25)
>   17:38:23.591690 IP .snmp > 1-1-1-1.ea.com.35403:  GetResponse(114)  system.sysDescr.0="Linux ip-17-3-2-2 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) x86_64"
>   17:38:24.592491 IP 1-1-1-1.ea.com.35403 > .snmp:  GetNextRequest(25)

But the result in local server is:

> Timeout: No Response from 1.1.1.1